# Apply registry proxy changes

Tags: batch-file, command-line, proxy, cmd

I am trying to make a batch file that changes proxy settings when run. Currently it changes the settings, however they are not applied unless I go to internet properties > LAN settings. Once I open LAN settings the changes are applied.

How can I make it so that the changes the batch file make are applied without needing to open the LAN Settings options?

```
@echo off
REM Enable Proxy
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^ /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /D 1 /f

REM Change Proxy settings
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^ /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d proxyserver:proxyport /f

REM Bylass Local
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^ /v ProxyOverride /t REG_SZ /d "*.my.domain;.other.domain;<local>" /f

pause
```

Comment: Would it help to `taskkill /im "explorer.exe"` then relaunch `explorer.exe`?  If not, and if no one comes up with a better solution, you could automate opening LAN settings.  `control inetcpl.cpl` then use Windows Script Host (VBScript or JScript) to `oshShell.SendKeys('+{TAB}{RIGHT 4}%L~~')`.

Comment: Taskkill didn't do the trick and unfortunately I don't know VBS. What I've done is add    control inetcpl.cpl,connections,4 to the last line so the user only needs to click LAN Settings to apply the changes. Hopefully someone can think of a better solution.